# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1 + n)}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + n}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, equivalence-relations

I have found this in part of a proof from https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap03/3.2/, question 3.2-5:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1 + n)}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + n}$

I'm not able see how to go from one to the next. I understand the idea that lg(1+n) is smaller than n.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hôpital's_rule

Comment: @Tavish Wouldn't this mean that it should be $\frac{1}{(1+n)\ln(2)}$

Comment: No, not at all.